# Shutdown mongoDb server with c# driver 2.2.3

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

With previous version of C# drivers (1.x) I could do :

```cs
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
var server = client.GetServer();
server.Shutdown();
```

How can I do this with driver version 2.2.3 ?

**Update**

Well the best I could find is something like this :

```cs
try
{
    var client = new MongoClient(settings);
    var adminDatabase = client.GetDatabase("admin");
    var cmd = new BsonDocument("shutdown", 1);
    adminDatabase.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(cmd);
}
catch (MongoConnectionException e)
{
    if (!(e.InnerException is EndOfStreamException))
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

but I dont really like this, the Try/catch etc ...

Comment: Have you tried running this with 2.2.3? I'm sure you can mix using the legacy API with the new API in the same program as the 2.2.3 driver continues to support almost all of the legacy API. Refer to the [API](https://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.2/html/Methods_T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient.htm).

Comment: Yes I tried with the 2.2.3 legacy but it appear that the Shutdown() method does not exist with this version

Comment: It appears that you need to select the Admin database, and run the method TResult RunCommand<TResult>(Command<TResult> command) with the command text of "shutdown," but I can't find any documentation as to how to turn the command text into Command<TResult>.

Comment: This question really needs a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

They told me at the [Google Groups Page](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/mongodb-user/STPkwSBaxdk) that is because it should never be used from most applications.

Craig Wilson mentioned that shutdown is simply a command that can be send using

```
db.RunCommand("{shutdown: 1}")
```

So it isn't anymore available in the API .net Version 2.0.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I could find after some intensive searching today. I am using the MongoDB C# driver 2.2. There are no special credentials to my mongod instance, it is all default settings. I would imagine this code would change a bit if there are special login credentials for the admin database.

```
// Connecting. 1 DB for actual usage, 1 for running the shutdown command
Client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
Database = Client.GetDatabase(DBName);
AdminDatabase = Client.GetDatabase("admin");

// Shutting down the DB "cleanly"
AdminDatabase.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{shutdown: 1}"));
```

From what I can tell by watching the mongod instance in a command prompt my application successfully connects, writes, reads, and then shuts down the mongod instance with `dbexit: rc: 0` which from what I can tell means it shutdown correctly, I faintly remember seeing `dbexit: rc: 12` when shutting down that way I was before (don't even ask).

Comment: Actually, for whatever reason, this seems to only work part of the time. I am not sure what or why is happening but sometimes when mongod is shutdown this way it does not properly release the lock. My first guess is that it is being shutdown while the other `Database` is busy writing (holding the lock) and the shutdown sequence does not wait for this to finish?

Comment: Perhapse it is because you dont 'await' the RunCommandAsync ?

Comment: Hmm... It's definitely worth a shot. Possibly destructing my connections to the DB before it has shutdown fully is my issue...

Comment: Hmm. If I `await` the command then an exception is thrown with the text "An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server" and the exception type is `MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException`. So.. This might be good. I would assume the server has shutdown before the result of the command can be passed back. // With some nice `try`/`catch` and possibly a timeout I think this could work "ok".